# Definition of smooth maps between manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, coordinate-systems

Here is a page from Guillemin-Pollack's differential topology:

[image]

**My question is**: At the bottom he defines $df=d\psi\circ dh\circ d\phi^{-1}$. Why doesn't he just define $df=dh$, like here: http://www.math.toronto.edu/mat1300/smoothmaps.4.pdf? It makes computations easier. Does one imply the other?

Answer (score 1):

You can't say that $df=dh$ since the domains are different. Notice that $df_{(x,y)}$ is a linear transformation from $T_{p}(x)$ to $T_{y}(Y)$ while $dh_{(0,0)}$ is a  linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{t}$.

You define $df$ using the coordinate charts that you would need if you want to do explicit calculations. However, you can prove that the definition doesn't depend on what coordinate chart you choose.

I can't see the definition you suggest in your link, but see that at the beginning $G$ is defined as a composition, $G= \psi\circ F\circ\phi^{−1}$,
 which gives you the coordinate expression for $F$. Then you can do everything using $G$ and $dG$ since the results are independent of the coordinates.

Comment: But why using $dG$ for everything is allowed then? As you said it is not the derivative of $F$.

Comment: If you defined $G'$ by choosing another chart $\Psi'$ and $\phi'^{-1}$ then you will have the linear map $dG'$ that relates to $dG$ by a change of basis. Notions like rank and kernel will remain invariant under the change of basis. So it doesn't matter what charts you use. If you want you can use $dG'$ instead of $dG$ and because they remain invariant  $dF$ is well defined.

Comment: $dG$ is the coordinate representation of $dF$ when you use the charts $\Psi$ and $\phi$.